# Create instance of a class in the hilt in the another module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I have 5 modules (main, splash, pick location, permissions, preferences).

I want to use the Preferences module in Splash and PickLocation.

This is the flow of my modules: Splash -> PickLocation

When I want to use the DataStore class in the PickLocation module to save new locations, I have a problem:

If I create a new instance of the DataStore class in the Splash module and create another instance of the same class in the PickLocation module DataStore not working, but if i just create an instance in the PickLocation everything is working. how can I use dagger hilt to create one instance and access from all modules?

**Preference module DI:**

```
package com.mykuyaclient.preference.di

import android.content.Context
import com.mykuyaclient.preference.datastores.CheckLocationIsSetDataStore
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object PreferenceModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideCheckLocationIsSetDataStore(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): CheckLocationIsSetDataStore =
        CheckLocationIsSetDataStore(appContext)
}
```

**PickLocationScreen codes:**

```
@Composable
fun MapScreen(navigatorViewModel: PickLocationViewModel) {
    **val context = LocalContext.current
    val dataStore = CheckLocationIsSetDataStore(context = context)**
    Surface(color = AppColor.ThemeColor.BACKGROUND) {
        val mapView = rememberMapViewWithLifecycle()
        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                MapViewContainer(mapView, navigatorViewModel)
                MapPinOverlay()

                Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {
                    Button(
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE,
                            contentColor = AppColor.neutralColor.DOCTOR
                        ),
                        onClick = {
                            navigatorViewModel.apply {
//                                popBackStack()
                                navigate(HomeDestination.route())
                                **viewModelScope.launch {
                                    dataStore.set(
                                        this@apply.location.value
                                    )
                                    
                                }**
                            }
                        }) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.confirm_address),
                            style = AppFont.PoppinsTypography.button
                        )
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SplashScreen codes:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
private fun SplashView(
    modifier: Modifier,
    multiplePermissionsState: MultiplePermissionsState,
    navigator: SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    **val context = LocalContext.current
    val dataStore = CheckLocationIsSetDataStore(context = context)**
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE)
            .padding(start = 64.dp, end = 64.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.Center)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mykuyatm),
                contentDescription = "mykuya tm image"
            )
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mykuya_powered_by),
                contentDescription = "mykuya powered by image"
            )
        }
        Loading(modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))
        FeatureThatRequiresPermission(
            multiplePermissionsState = multiplePermissionsState, permissionsState = {
                if (it) {
                    navigator.apply {
                        viewModelScope.launch {
                            delay(Constants.SPLASH_DELAY)
                            **dataStore.get.collect { model ->
                                model.let {
                                   /* if (model.lat == Constants.IF_LOCATION_LAT_NOT_SET && model.lat == Constants.IF_LOCATION_LNG_NOT_SET) {
                                        navigate(PickLocationDestination.route())
                                    }else{
                                        navigate(HomeDestination.route())
                                    }*/
                                    navigate(PickLocationDestination.route())
                                }
                            }**

//                            popBackStack()

                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**DataStore class codes: (How can i use instance of this class in the all of modules)**

```
class CheckLocationIsSetDataStore @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) :
    IDataStore<Location, Location> {
    override val get: Flow<Location>
        get() = context.dataStore.data.catch { exception ->
            if (exception is IOException) {
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            } else {
                throw exception
            }
            Log.e("DataStore Exception: ", exception.toString())
        }.map { preferences ->
            Location("").let {
                it.latitude = preferences[DataStoreKeys.IS_LOCATION_LAT_SET_KEY]
                    ?: Constants.IF_LOCATION_LAT_NOT_SET
                it.longitude = preferences[DataStoreKeys.IS_LOCATION_LNG_SET_KEY]
                    ?: Constants.IF_LOCATION_LNG_NOT_SET
                it
            }
        }

    override suspend fun set(param: Location?) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
               preferences[DataStoreKeys.IS_LOCATION_LAT_SET_KEY] =
                   param?.latitude ?: Constants.IF_LOCATION_LAT_NOT_SET
               preferences[DataStoreKeys.IS_LOCATION_LNG_SET_KEY] =
                   param?.longitude ?: Constants.IF_LOCATION_LNG_NOT_SET
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hilt can inject dependencies in view models, so you need to create such a model.

Here is a basic example:

```
class CheckLocationIsSetDataStore @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context
) {
    fun dataStore() = context.dataStore
    
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "composePreferences")
}

@HiltViewModel
class DataStoreProviderViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val checkLocationIsSetDataStore: CheckLocationIsSetDataStore,
): ViewModel() {
    private val key = booleanPreferencesKey("some_test_key")

    val get get() = checkLocationIsSetDataStore.dataStore().data.catch { exception ->
        if (exception is IOException) {
            emit(emptyPreferences())
        } else {
            throw exception
        }
        Log.e("DataStore Exception: ", exception.toString())
    }.map { preferences ->
        preferences[key] ?: false
    }

    fun set(value: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            checkLocationIsSetDataStore.dataStore().edit {
                it[key] = value
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestScreen(
) {
    val viewModel = hiltViewModel<DataStoreProviderViewModel>()
    val some by viewModel.get.collectAsState(initial = false)
    Switch(checked = some, onCheckedChange = { viewModel.set(it) })
}
```

Comment: This ViewModel is specific for this class (CheckLocationIsSetDataStore)? or any screen ViewModel?

Comment: @saeednoshadi probably I choose a bad naming, but yes, it's specific to property. You can embed this code into your screen view model  or Inject it to avoid code duplication, or just use two view models for a screen (screen view model + data store view model)

Comment: I get this error:                           There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: /data/user/0/com.dev/files/datastore/client_preferences.preferences_pb. You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).                                                                      I used this viewModels code in the two screen view models in the splash module and pick location modul

Comment: I used    `private val checkLocationIsSetDataStore: CheckLocationIsSetDataStore` in the both of viewModels

Comment: @saeednoshadi Looks like you've solved this multi DataStores problem by yourself?